# Proof: for martingale that $E(X_{n\geq m}|F_m)=X_m$ (by induction).

Tags: solution-verification, expected-value, martingales, recursion

I just wanted to know if my proof by induction of this statement $E(X_{n\geq m}|F_m)=X_m$ for a martingal is correct?

*initialisation:* $E(X_{n+1}|F_n)=X_n$ by def of a martingale
*assumption:* $\forall k \in \mathbb{N},E(X_{n+k}|F_n)=X_n$
*step:* As $F_n\subseteq F_{n+k}$ so $E(X_{n+k+1}|F_n)=E(E(X_{n+k+1}|F_{n+k})|F_n)=E(X_{n+k}|F_n)=X_n$
More precisally using this justification:
-$E(X_{n+k+1}|F_{n+k})=X_{n+k}$ by definition of a martingale
-$E(X_{n+k}|F_n)=X_n$ by assumption

Q.E.D
Is it correct?

Comment: it is correct. but better to write $E(X_n|F_m)=X_m\forall n\ge m$.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank for your answer. Can you please post an answer (and not a comment as you just did) to my question like that i will be able to mark my question (and your answer) as solved? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is correct.

> it is correct. but better to write E(Xn|Fm)=Xm∀n≥m. –
> Kurt G.
> Sep 28 at 10:56